# How to include multi colums or row from database

Tags: php

Hello as you see on my code i have ony firstname inclduded i wanna include and "lastname" but is not working idk why?

```
<li><?php if ($AuthUser): ?>
  <a  href="<?= APPURL."/profile/" ?>"><?= __("Welcome, %s", htmlchars($AuthUser->get("firstname"))) ?></a></li>
<li> <?php else: ?>
```

Comment: For example i want not only "firstname" but another "thing"

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a framework. Which one is it?

Comment: @bassxzero no framework, core PHP with Lua.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. 
You should read this [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Anyone will help?

Comment: What have you tried to include *other things* ? What errors you get?